# Stripe API: Accessing Coupon Data

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the coupon id from a customer record using the Stripe API. I think I'm referencing it the wrong way. I've tried this:

```
 $cust = \Stripe\Customer::all(array("limit" => 3));

    if(!empty($cust)){

        foreach ($cust->data as $customer){

           foreach ($customer->subscriptions as $sub)
           {
                echo $sub->discount->coupon->id;

            } 

        }     
    }else{
        //No Customers
    }
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes from your echo line.

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors in your log files? How about the Stripe logs?

Comment: To debug this type of thing, just before you echo the coupon you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php to inspect the variable 
(i.e. `var_dump($sub);`).  Then if it's what you expect, you could do `var_dump($sub->discount);`, then `var_dump($sub->discount->coupon);`, etc. to see where it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

As recommended above, you're outputting a variable with single quotes around it, which will output that string literally vs inserting the contents of the `$sub->discount->coupon->id` variable in the string. Either remove the single quotes or, if you fancy string interpolation, replace what you have with `echo "{$sub->discount->coupon->id}";`

You also need to loop over `$customer->subscriptions->data` as the subscriptions array has the same shape as the customers array:

```
$cust = \Stripe\Customer::all(array("limit" => 3, "expand" => "data.subscriptions"));

if(!empty($cust)){

    foreach ($cust->data as $customer){

       foreach ($customer->subscriptions->data as $sub)
       {
            if ($sub->discount && $sub->discount->coupon) {
               echo $sub->discount->coupon->id . "\n";
            }
       } 

    }

} else {
    // No Customers
}
```

I also added an `if` statement to avoid errors when `$sub->discount` or `$sub->discount->coupon` are null.

Have a look at the example output here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_subscription

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I retrieve Customer data from Stripe the response includes the Subscription data that I want to acesss. I think parsing the JSON is the issue here.

Comment: Just updated my response, you're right that the part about expanding objects wasn't needed. If you have further problems, please post any error message, as well as describing what you're seeing vs what you expected to see, etc.